# Jquery string comparison

Tags: jquery

I am trying to compare if 2 image paths are equal but i can't make it work. Here is my code

```
$("#productImg img").click(function(){
 var img = $(this).attr("src");
    var smallImage = $("#largeImg img").attr("src").replace('si_', 'th');

    if(img == smallImage){
        alert('match');
    }else{
        alert('not a match');
    }
 });
```

Bellow are image tags

```
 <img id="zoomImage" src="products/beddingSupplies/beddingSuppliesDuvet/img/si_1.jpg" />
 <img id="zoomImage" src="products/beddingSupplies/beddingSuppliesDuvet/img/th_1.jpg" />
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: now why wouldn't you include the `html`?

Comment: Well, what are the values of `img` and `smallImage`?

Comment: I thought it was unnecessary to.

Comment: @Antegeia: Well, the HTML likely contains the values you are trying to compare, so of course it's necessary.

Comment: first image src is image/th_1.jpg  , second image is image/si_2.jpg , thats why i am replacing.

Comment: you are aware that 1 !== 2, yes?

Comment: you're replacing si_ with just th.  Is that the problem?

Comment: @Felix Kling: src it looks the same in the eye, all case sensitive and stuff, but ok i will post html too

Comment: @Barbara Laird: omg how did i miss that? Thanks so much man, you save my night!!!

Answer (score 1):

you forgot an underscore:

```
 var smallImage = $("#largeImg img").attr("src").replace('si_', 'th_');
```